# Create Dynamic Content via API

Tags: rest-api, soap, pardot

I am trying to wrap my head round the Pardot API. Our usecase involves been able to create dynamic content via API. On inspecting the the documentation, it appears that we can only query it (http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/dynamic-content/).

Has anyone been able to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create Dynamic Content view the API. The only 2 operations available are `query` and `read`.

Source: I maintain pypardot4, the Python wrapper for the Pardot API.